# Django: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'number'

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Here is my code:

**urls.py: **

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from base_app import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'base_app'

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^forms/$', views.form, name='form'),
   url(r'^tables/$', views.table, name='table'),
   url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
   url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
   url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),# line added
]
```

**views.py: **

```
def form(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = FormName(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = FormName()
        return render(request, 'base_app/form-samples.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})

    return render(request, 'base_app/form-samples.html')
```

**models.py: **

```
class InfoForm(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='username')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256, default='email')
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=256, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py: **

```
class FormName(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InfoForm
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'number')
```

after that when I run, `python manage.py migrate`

I get this message -> `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:` 'number'`

Where is the problem?

Comment: If the error is in a migration, you should show that migration, and not the irrelevant forms, views and URLs.

Comment: I can help to show some lines of the stack trace too, to see where the error occurs exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but I don't think Django will like you setting the ```default='email'``` on an ```EmailField``` as this isn't technically valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PositiveIntegerField doesn't support max_length option. It's range is from 0 to 2147483647.

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
...
number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(256)])
```

Comment: i got this:  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_value'. also when i say: number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True). i get this exception again: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'number'`

Comment: You can solve it using MaxValueValidator as well. I've update my answer to reflect that.